# How to map query string to Dictionary of List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm using C# Asp.Net MVC and I want to get filters as parameter in my controller action.

I have a query string for filters.
It is looks like so:

```
?page=2&groups%5B0%5D=group1&groups%5B1%5D=group2&category%5B0%5D=category1
```

How could I parse it to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Or to `List<Filter>`?

```
class Filter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is case of custom model binding. we can create one by inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder`:

```
 public class SearchModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private NameValueCollection _queryString;

        private List<string> GetValues(string key)
        {
            return (_queryString.GetValues(key) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).ToList();
        }

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            _queryString = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

            return _queryString.AllKeys.Select(x => new Filter { Name = x, Values = GetValues(x) }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

And then in controller action (notice parameter attribute)

```
  public ActionResult Search([ModelBinder(typeof(SearchModelBinder))] List<Filter> filter)
    {
            // do something with filter
            return Content(filter.LastOrDefault()?.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In any action you already have some kind of query dictionary. Take a look at

```
HttpContext.Request.Query
```

It contains property `Keys` and related to each key value

Comment: Yes, I know. but I hope it is possible to make it by default binder.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
   keyValue.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key] ?? string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not for Dictionary<string, List<string>>. I believe default model binder will make such mapping without and additional actions.

Comment: i think, ?page=2&groups[0]=group1&groups[1]=group2&category[0]=category1 would map to defaultbinder